# Is this use of std::promise thread safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, promise

Consider this code:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <future>

std::promise<int> prom;

void thr_func(int n)
{
    prom.set_value(n + 10);
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t{thr_func, 5};

    auto fut = prom.get_future();

    int result = fut.get();
    std::cout << result << std::endl;

    t.join();
}
```

The `prom` object is accessed concurrently and even though the standard says that `set_value` is atomic, I cannot find anything about `get_future` being atomic (or const).

Therefore I wonder whether it is correct to call `get_future` this way.

Comment: you aren't calling get_future from multiple threads in this code, so I'm not sure what your question is.

Comment: If you would actually invoke `set_value` several times on the same promise, wouldn't this yield a `promise_already_satisfied` `std::future_error`?

Comment: @xaxxon `main` and `thr_func` run in different threads

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are right that the standard does not say anything about `get_future` being atomic. It is probably not safe to call it concurrently with `set_value`.

Instead, call `get_future` before thread creation. That guarantees it is called before `set_value`.

```
auto fut = prom.get_future();

std::thread t{thr_func, 5};

...
```